# stop calling onLocationChanged() when activity is paused

Tags: android

I am sending latitude and longitude values continuously to the server .I implemented LocationListener in service class.When onPause method is invoke in activity i need to stop the sending values to server.
I used following code but not working .`stopService(new Intent(this, LocationMonitoringService.class));`

Can anyone help me with this ??
Thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't this working? What are your observations?

Comment: if you are using fused location provider you can use `mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);`

Comment: service is not  stopping even though i used that

Comment: What type of your service, started or bound?

Comment: use onStart() to start service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution for,Add onDestroy() in fragment.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mLocationClient != null && mLocationClient.isConnected()) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationClient, this);
    }
}
```